# Specifying random slopes for only one nested group using lmer - mixed model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have  data which is crop yield over multiple years and locations. Locations are nested within a province. There are 5 provinces. I want to specify a model where the time trend (year variable) varies by location but not by province. Also I want to specify the model to show locations are nested within province. Is this the correct way of specifying such a model in lmer.

```
lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (year|location) + (1|province/location), data = dat)
```

The location and province are coded as

```
province 1 -  location as 11, 12, 13, 14 etc
province 2 - location as 21, 22, 23, 24 etc 
province 3 - location as 31, 32, 33, 34 etc.
```

Comment: what is your `state` variable? that's not in your verbal description at all ... is it supposed to be `location`?

Comment: Sorry yes it is supposed to be a location. I have provided more info on how my location and province are coded

Answer (score 0):

If your locations are *uniquely coded*, i.e. in provinces A, B, C, D, E you have states A1, A2, A3, ..., B1, B2, B3, ..., C1, C2, C3, ..., then `(year|location)` is sufficient to specify random variation in intercepts and slopes across locations (based on the edits to your question, this is indeed the case).

If they were not (i.e. your locations were labeled 1, 2, 3, ... , 1, 2, 3, ... 1, 2, 3, ...) then you would need `(year|province:location)`, where `:` indicates an interaction.

- `(year|province/location)` would denote random intercepts and slopes among both provinces and locations within provinces.
- In either case, `(1|province/location)` looks wrong/unnecessary.
- It seems weird to assume there is exactly *zero* variation in intercepts and slopes among provinces.